# Homemade Preserves

Tags: food-safety, canning

I was given 3 different jars of preserves.  They left the jars in the car for 2 days in the heat of Nevada and when they gave to me you could see the jams had turned to liquid.  After leaving on the counter overnight the jams are solid.  Are they safe to eat?

Answer (score 6):

If they were properly canned to begin with, the seals are still intact, and there there is no bulging of the lid or other signs of spoilage, then yes - they are still safe to eat. They liquified because they got too hot and melted, that's normal. Pectin can liquify and re-gel repeatedly. That may affect the overall quality and tastiness of the preserves, but if the seals are intact you're fine. The seal may be somewhat weakened by the experience, so I'd open and enjoy them sooner rather than later.